# Header redirection php code won't work

Tags: php, html

i want to redirect links, something like shortcut URL

```
<?php
$hosted_url=$_GET['url'];
header( '$hosted_url' ) ;
?>
```

but when i try this http://example.com/test.php?url=http://google.com
nothing happend
how to make this code work and redirect links

Comment: `header("Location:...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the actual header to send. Per the [documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
header("Location: ".$hosted_url);
```